# Label tag colors based on value

Tags: php, html

I have a basic web site that collects customers information. The data table that I have has a status column (approved, pending). I would like to show a colored label on the status value it gets from the database.

```
  <table cellspacing="0" width="100%" id="example" class="table table-striped table-hover table-responsive">
    <thead>
    <tr>
    <th> ID</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Location</th>
    <th>Status</th>
    </tr>

            <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row['call_id']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['name']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['city'] . ', ' .$row['state']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['status']; ?></td>
```

When form submitted if the status (which is a option list) is approved value= 1
in the data table I'm wanting it to be like a green box that says approved. 
I apologize this is my first web site.

Comment: This is not a question.

Comment: added code and explained a little more thanks for the help

Comment: Do a conditional on `$row['status']`, then apply a class. `$class = !empty($row['status']) : ' class="green" ? '';` then make a CSS rule..

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
<?php if ($row['status'] == 1) { ?>
    <td class="green"><?php echo $row['status']; ?></td>
<?php } else { ?>
    <td class="otherColor"><?php echo $row['status']; ?></td>
<?php } ?>
```

and your css:

```
.green { background-color: green; }
.otherColor { background-color: /*some other color you want */; }
```